# Margin between card with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I have some card with bootstrap and I would like to have left margin...I would like the cards to be evenly distributed across the width.
Basically, You can see that there is red on the right, and I wish there wasn't...

```css
.azer {
  background: red;
}

.card-annuaire {
  background: green;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}

.card-annuaire .card-body {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-center my-5">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="qsdf">
        <div class="azer">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="row g-0">
              <div class="col-md-3 grid-item-annuaire letter-<?= $first_letter; ?>">
                <div class="card card-annuaire mb-4">
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="card-text entry-content"><img src="https://picsum.photos/100" />
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.card-text -->
                  </div>
                  <!-- /.card-body -->
                </div>
                <!-- /.card  -->
              </div>
              <!-- /.col  -->
              <div class="col-md-3 grid-item-annuaire letter">
                <div class="card card-annuaire mb-4">
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="card-text entry-content"><img src="https://picsum.photos/100" alt="pic" />
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.card-text -->
                  </div>
                  <!-- /.card-body -->
                </div>
                <!-- /.card  -->
              </div>
              <!-- /.col  -->
              <div class="col-md-3 grid-item-annuaire letter-<?= $first_letter; ?>">
                <div class="card card-annuaire mb-4">
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="card-text entry-content"><img src="https://picsum.photos/100" />
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.card-text -->
                  </div>
                  <!-- /.card-body -->
                </div>
                <!-- /.card  -->
              </div>
              <!-- /.col  -->
              <div class="col-md-3 grid-item-annuaire letter-<?= $first_letter; ?>">
                <div class="card card-annuaire mb-4">
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="card-text entry-content"><img src="https://picsum.photos/100" />
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.card-text -->
                  </div>
                  <!-- /.card-body -->
                </div>
                <!-- /.card  -->
              </div>
              <!-- /.col  -->
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can see here: https://codepen.io/zazzou/pen/abYdZQL

EDIT
This is what I would like to do : (no margin left and right before and after the first card and last card)
[image: my image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `margin-right: 1rem;` from the `.card-annuaire` class, and replace `g-0` on your `row` class to `gx-3`. This adds gutters in between your cards

Edit: Check this link out for more info on how gutters work in bootstrap: [Bootstrap Gutters](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/layout/gutters/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove margin right from `.card-annuaire` Like this:

```
.card-annuaire {
      background:green;
            border:0;
            border-radius: 0;
            .card-body {
                text-align: center;
            }
```

### Update

If you margin on both sides then you can do:

```
.card-annuaire {
      background:green;
            border:0;
            border-radius: 0;
            margin:0 1rem;
            .card-body {
                text-align: center;
            }
```

```css
.azer {
  background: red;
}

.card-annuaire {
  background:green;
        border:0;
        border-radius: 0;
        margin:0 1rem;
        .card-body {
            text-align: center;
        }
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-center my-5">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="qsdf" >
        <div class="azer">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="row g-0">
              <div class="col-md-3 grid-item-annuaire letter-<?= $first_letter; ?>">
                <div class="card card-annuaire mb-4">
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="card-text entry-content"><img src="https://picsum.photos/100" />
                    </div><!-- /.card-text -->
                  </div><!-- /.card-body -->
                </div><!-- /.card  -->
              </div><!-- /.col  -->
              <div class="col-md-3 grid-item-annuaire letter">
                <div class="card card-annuaire mb-4">
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="card-text entry-content"><img src="https://picsum.photos/100" alt="pic" />
                    </div><!-- /.card-text -->
                  </div><!-- /.card-body -->
                </div><!-- /.card  -->
              </div><!-- /.col  -->
              <div class="col-md-3 grid-item-annuaire letter-<?= $first_letter; ?>">
                <div class="card card-annuaire mb-4">
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="card-text entry-content"><img src="https://picsum.photos/100" />
                    </div><!-- /.card-text -->
                  </div><!-- /.card-body -->
                </div><!-- /.card  -->
              </div><!-- /.col  -->
              <div class="col-md-3 grid-item-annuaire letter-<?= $first_letter; ?>">
                <div class="card card-annuaire mb-4">
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="card-text entry-content"><img src="https://picsum.photos/100" />
                    </div><!-- /.card-text -->
                  </div><!-- /.card-body -->
                </div><!-- /.card  -->
              </div><!-- /.col  -->
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If I remove this margin, all my cards are stuck... But I want to have space between them.

Comment: I can't understand. You wanted to remove the margin on right, I answered about the same things, rest is working fine. Can you elaborate please how are the cards stuck?

Answer (score 0):

- Restore the column gutters
- Make the cards full width
- Place the red background on the row rather than a separate element

```css
.azer {
  background: red;
}

.card-annuaire {
  width: 100%;
  background: green;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}

.card-annuaire .card-body {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-center my-5">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="qsdf">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="row azer">
            <div class="col-md-3 grid-item-annuaire letter-<?= $first_letter; ?>">
              <div class="card card-annuaire mb-4">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <div class="card-text entry-content"><img src="https://picsum.photos/100" />
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-3 grid-item-annuaire letter">
              <div class="card card-annuaire mb-4">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <div class="card-text entry-content"><img src="https://picsum.photos/100" alt="pic" />
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-3 grid-item-annuaire letter-<?= $first_letter; ?>">
              <div class="card card-annuaire mb-4">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <div class="card-text entry-content"><img src="https://picsum.photos/100" />
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-3 grid-item-annuaire letter-<?= $first_letter; ?>">
              <div class="card card-annuaire mb-4">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <div class="card-text entry-content"><img src="https://picsum.photos/100" />
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```